# What is the DNA sequence of an apple?

Tags: botany, dna, genomes, fruit

I read that the genome for [*Malus Domestica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple) was mapped, but I can't find a sequence anywhere.

If this is a stupid question, I would appreciate if you would please tell me where I am wrong in this!

Comment: Googled "malus domestica genome sequence". First result was [this paper](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v42/n10/full/ng.654.html), which includes this [genome bank entry](https://www.rosaceae.org/species/malus/malus_x_domestica/genome_v1.0) (which is also the second search result)

Comment: @Luigi Thanks, but I don't know how to make sense of the genome bank entry

Comment: If all you want is to download the sequence of all the chromosomes, look at the [haplotype assembly](https://www.rosaceae.org/node/482). Download the first file (psuedomolecules) and unzip it. Then you'll have the sequence of each chromosome in FASTA format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.rosaceae.org/species/malus/malus_x_domestica/genome_v1.0

You can see the data in the URL above. The details are described in [this article](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v42/n10/full/ng.654.html).

As others said, NCBI seems useful.
Go to [this site](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCA_000148765.1).
Chose chromosome you want to see and click genebank or refsequence corresponding to the chromosome in the table (Assembly Unit: Primary Assembly). 
You can see overview of the sequence.
Find FASTA in the page showing the overview and click FASTA. Then the sequence data will be downloaded.

Comment: Thank you, I had a look at the above link, but I'm still not seeing the DNA nucleotide sequence.

Comment: The sequence data is shown like https://www.rosaceae.org/gb/gbrowse/malus_x_domestica/ You might be able to extract sequences from this. But I have not used this particular site. At least, you can see the conting sequences indicated in red by clicking the red areas like https://www.rosaceae.org/gb/malus_details?id=1311210

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the DNA database at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ to find the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the apple genome on NCBI.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=Apple

Comment: How many lines of nucleotide sequences are there?

Comment: Are all sequence lines necessary?